# Google Analytics listing hundreds of pages because of Facebook tracking parameters but my site has 2 pages

Tags: google-analytics, url-parameters, page-views

Google Analytics is listing hundreds of pages on my site because Facebook is adding extra information in the slug (/?fblid=). I tried excluding it in URL query parameters using [this](https://www.glowmetrics.com/blog/what-is-fbclid-how-to-remove-fbclid-parameter-from-google-analytics/#gref) tutorial and I tried creating a Request URI filter using the string: (fbclid=[^&]*&?) based on [this](https://holini.com/fbclid-parameter-google-analytics/) tutorial. Neither action did anything.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot of a Google Analytics page behavior list and graph]

Comment: Probably site got indexed for pages that have been maliciously added to the directory. Quickly scan your website. Thanks

Comment: @Emiley thank you. I'll see if that works. It looks like a tracking parameter issue, but the only tracking I have going is Google Analytics.

Comment: How long has it been since you excluded it? Historical data will not be edited, so if you look at a date range including days before you set up the filtration, it will still show the parameters.

Comment: @Reve ok! Thank you! I just excluded it today. Well, now I know. I just need to figure out how to read the data that I currently have. Any ideas? I did try a filter but without success.

Comment: If I were doing it, I'd export the data into a spreadsheet and use functions there to carve off the query parameter (this example: https://www.excelfunctions.net/split-string-in-excel.html#Split1stChar but with ? in place of space; you could do that in a column inserted between the original page and the metrics). Then you can use a pivot table to sum over the now-identical pages.

Comment: Or, if you don't have a lot of pages you need data for, you could filter to just that collection and use the sums at the top of the table. For the non-homepages putting /get-your-copy/ or /thank-you/ would work, for the homepage this regex: ^/(\?.*)?$ Meaning: start with slash, optionally have a question mark followed by anything, then end.

Comment: @Reve do you know if there is any way to see the data properly in GA, loike maybe using a filter? I don't want to have my data split between a spreadsheet and the app. If not, then I can probably start over. It's not good data anyway, because there were weeks when the page wasn't working or the button wasn't working.

Comment: You can't edit the historical data, but it's possible the Content Drilldown report might batch the pages together in the way you want (under Behavior > Site Content). Also, this may have been clear, but "filter" in my previous comment meant the search bar at the top of the report table. If you've just got the 3 pages of interest you can look at them one by one that way.

Comment: @Reve thank you. I can't tell if what I did is working yet. I'm not promoting my page at the moment so I don't have any new traffic since I made the change haha. Is there someone you recommend you creates good tutorials on GA? I'm totally new to it.

Comment: For written descriptions, I like the official documentation: https://support.google.com/analytics/topic/3544907 Loves Data has a lot of shorter videos, unfortunately with multiple GA versions mixed together in the playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1vNrn711L8T2NS2kFLBTipUefFLSQopf Weboq has longer, more general videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDL6dB5L21OE5tmOhUsGqpMaqI0XfO4sb Both are good!

Comment: Also there's no substitute for going through your own GA and clicking on everything. There are some reports that are kind of hidden under links, like the Navigation Summary tab near the top of the Behavior > Site Content > All Pages report. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, @Reve! I really appreciate your help!